# How to book a hotel in Havana?

Tags: hotels, cuba, havana

I have difficulty booking a hotel in Havana from Feb 1 - Feb 4 in 2016.

What would be the best way to book hotels in Cuba?

Comment: Pick a non-US based travel booking website and search there? (Almost all US-based websites won't be able to book you into a Cuban hotel due to the trade embargo still in place)

Comment: What is the "difficulty" you're having? Is it a legal difficulty with US law? Is your credit card issuer declining the purchase? Are you unable to read Spanish?

Comment: @gagravarr Thanks for your advice but I haven't found a good website which is non-US based yet. Would you recommend one for me?

Comment: Purely as an example: http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotels-g147271-Havana_Cuba-Hotels.html It's possible that these websites can detect that you are in the US and refuse to give you information about Cuba.

Comment: @Calchas I think the legal things doesn't matter to me since I am Korean. I usually book hotels on US based websites such as booking.com so far, but I could not find a good one yet.

Comment: @HanulLee It *must* be a non-US based website, doesn't matter where in the world you are, it's where they are that matters. One option is to search for hotels on tripadvisor, then google for those hotel names and book on one of those sites. For an English language site, another option is to pick a UK site like [Trivago](trivago.co.uk) or [Hotels Combined](hotelscombined.co.uk) (amongst many many others) and look there. Or pick any Spanish one

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for your kind advice. As you taught me, I'm trying to book hotels on the sites google shows, but it is very limited. I think it is impossible to book 5-stars hotels for the days I wrote above.

Comment: Does anybody know how to book 5-stars hotels in Havana from 1 Feb to 4 Feb?

Comment: I did a quick search before writing the comment, for your exact dates, and found several bookable in just a few minutes of searching. Given your repeated problems at following our advise, I'd suggest you just got to a "bricks and mortar" travel agent and pay them to sort it for you

Comment: @HanulLee Booking.com is not US-based. It's based in the Netherlands. But it's been bought by Priceline, which might be why it does not allow you to book hotels in Cuba.

Answer (score 5):

As you have apparently found, due to the fact that the trade embargo with Cuba remains, you can't book on any US websites, nor any US based websites. That means not only the obvious "US version of Foo.com", but also "any other country like the UK's version of US-based Foo.com". (Insert many major hotel booking websites here). If you try, you either can't search because it won't show Cuba, or it'll give you an error like this one on Kayak:

[image: Kayak error]

There are plenty of other websites out there that will let you book though, you just need to find them!

First up, you need to find the name of a likely hotel in your price bracket in the area you want. You can search for eg "5 star hotel Havana Cuba", or go on a website like TripAdvisor, or check some blogs, or check some non-US hotel companies. The least we need is a hotel name, but ideally also a selection.

Now, search for that hotel's name. If you found one you really liked, great! Try a few of the booking sites that come up, check for the lowest price (might be on the hotel's own site), and book. If not, find a general hotel booking site showing that hotel, then search there for hotels in Havana for your dates, and see all the hotels they offer

.

(Since the OP seems to be having a lot of trouble following these instructions, one such 5* Havana hotel you can easily find for a quick blog/advisor search is the [Melia Habana in Havana](http://www.melia.com/en/hotels/cuba/havana/melia-habana/index.html), which can be booked on the Melia site or dozens of third party hotel booking sites, and has availability on the dates mentioned. I've not stayed there, so I can't recommend it either way, it's just one example you can use to follow the later steps of the approach outlined above)